# Thunderbird client forgets email accounts

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird

I'm having difficulty solving an issue with Thunderbird, it seems to forget the linked account that it gets the mail from. I have done some research regarding this and have discovered that there are a couple of users that experience this problem but so far there is no solution. The operating system in question is Windows 7.

Comment: Please provide more information on how "it seems to forget".

Comment: The following day it is required to enter all the email accounts details, and the Pc wasn't even shut down